# Saving an Assembly as a byte array suitable for Assembly.Load

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies

I notice that Assembly.LoadFrom has the following overload

```
public static Assembly Load(
    byte[] rawAssembly
)
```

How do I save an assembly as a byte array in order to create it like this?

Context : I want to write a test harness that will ensure backward compatability of a service. I want to load canned versions of the client into my harness and call the service from many different versions. I think saving the old versions as byte[] would allow me to freeze them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have old versions as files (just as they were normally built) that's all you need. You can read those into a byte array (e.g. with `File.ReadAllBytes`) if you need to.

It sounds like you just need to keep the old binaries in source control.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllByes(assemblyPath);
```

NOTE that you will have to load dependent assemblies first.